# Why does this polymorphism not work python

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

Let us consider the following program:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self,name,shortDesc):
        self.name=name
        self.shortDesc=shortDesc

class Player(Object):
    def __init__(self,health,armor,room,inventory,wearing,gender,money):
        self.health=health
        self.armor=armor
        self.room=room
        self.inventory=inventory
        self.wearing=wearing
        self.gender=gender
        self.money=money

player=Player("Will","Amazing",100,0,"start",[],[],"Male",0)
```

Well, I'm not very well adjusted to polymorphism but I don't really understand why this doesn't work.Python appears to ask for the 8 parameters given by the Player class but does not account for the parameters in Object.

It is possible that what I am trying to do is impossible, and if so please correct me on how I could achieve a similar aim...

EDIT: Sorry, I'm a complete idiot... What I am saying is have I made some obvious bug due to my lack of understanding of inheritance or is it impossible to add your own parameters to an inherited function?

Comment: err what is `PERSON` here?

Comment: That was my mistake... I meant PLAYER.

Comment: `PLAYER` is not defined anywhere either. Please post *actual* code and explain what it is that you are trying to do, because the question isn't very obvious right now

Comment: @user2592835: then what is `PLAYER` here? You only have `Player`; Python is case sensitive.

Comment: Are you intentionally not calling the superclass constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you redefine a method in a subclass, it *replaces the original entirely*. You can still call the version in a parent class, but when addressing `Player.__init__` your *new* version is found.

As such, Python won't split your arguments across the `Player.__init__` and `Object.__init__` methods; you have to do so yourself, explicitly. Have `Player.__init__` accept all arguments for `Object.__init__` *as well*, then pass those up the chain:

```
class Player(Object):
    def __init__(self, name, description, 
                 health, armor, room, inventory, wearing, gender, money):
        super(Player, self).__init__(name, description)
        # rest of your Player initialisation.
```

I used the [`super()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) here to obtain a proxy object that gives you access to methods defined on parent classes, but you can also directly retrieve the unbound method:

```
class Player(Object):
    def __init__(self, name, description, 
                 health, armor, room, inventory, wearing, gender, money):
        Object.__init__(self, name, description)
        # rest of your Player initialisation.
```

but then you need to name that base class explicitly again, and pass in `self` explicitly to that method.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not what you're actually running, but the question is clear: You expect that the `__init__` function of the derived object should somehow be the combination of the two `__init__` functions, but this is not how it works. The child's `__init__` is the only one called for the child. If you want to supply arguments for the superclass, the derived class must accept them and pass them on to `Object.__init__` (which it must explicitly call).

This behavior is known as [*method overriding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding). Python doesn't have polymorphism in the java or C++ sense of [*method overloading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading): If you try to initialize a `Player` object with just two arguments, you will not trigger a call to `Object.__init__()`; you'll still be calling `Player.__init__()`, and get an error.

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to use new Python classes, this is, the parent class should inherit from `object`.
- Then you need to accept the parent class arguments in the child class. An easy way to do this is via the `*args` and `**kwargs` special parameters.
- And finally, you need to call the parent class `__init__` method and use named parameters to call the constructor.

---

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self,name,shortDesc, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name=name
        self.shortDesc=shortDesc

class Player(Object):
    def __init__(self,health,armor,room,inventory,wearing,gender,
                 money, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.health=health
        self.armor=armor
        self.room=room
        self.inventory=inventory
        self.wearing=wearing
        self.gender=gender
        self.money=money

player=Player(name="Will",shortDesc="Amazing",health=100,armor=0,
              room="start",inventory=[],wearing=[],gender="Male",money=0)
```

Comment: I get the error "must be type not classobj" when I add this solution to my code...

Comment: Are you inheriting from `object` in your `Object` class?